# Seeking titanium compound, melting point <1600 °C, decomposes to TiO

Tags: thermodynamics, synthesis, heat, melting-point

The title says it all.  I’m new to glass making, and I need a titanium compound that will render me $\ce{TiO}$ through decomposition, and has a melting point under 1600 °C.  Hopefully I can get one that goes under 1500 °C, because that’s the max these guys usually keep the furnace at.  The compounds I’ve found so far are typically in the 1800 °C range and we can’t do that.  Any input is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know how the decomposition reaction proceeds, but have a look at [titanite (formerly known as sphene) - CaTiSiO$_{5}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titanite). I Googled around and see a melting point at 1382$^{\circ}$ C. That said, there's silicon and calcium in the mix, so this might be a dead end for you (I know nothing about glass making).

Comment: Obviously this isn't decomposition so may be completely useless to you, but anyway; I believe TiO can be made by reacting TiO2 and Ti at ~1500c.

Comment: I believe, if you can make it and survive it, titanium oxonitride would fill the bill (*shudders*). Otherwise, consider mixed oxides.

Comment: The real question here is "why do you need it?" I don't know that much about glass making as well, but for me the preparation of high-temperature glass sealants usually goes like this: (a) mix the components - oxides, carbonates, whatever (b) heat the bastards in the inert crucible. The components will decompose, melt, interact and dissolve each other. Even if the melting point of any individual component is higher than the melting point of resulting glass, there shouldn't be a problem because of eutectics. My point is that I don't see why you cannot just add some $\ce{TiO2}$ to your glass.

Comment: My guess is to use $\ce{TiCl2}$ (m.p 1035 C). It disproportionate to $\ce{TiCl4}$ at high temp. which can be then hydrolyzed to $\ce{TiO2}$. This is then can be decomposed or converted to $\ce{TiO}$.

Comment: try TiO2 + Ti at higher pressure and temperature